# Git: How to merge a small, but very old branch?

Tags: git, svn, merge, branch

We're migrating from SVN, and also merging a bunch of branches. To massively simplify, we have a branch B which was forked a long time ago, and has a little bit of development, let's say 8 files modified, out of hundreds. Meanwhile, huge changes have happened on master:

```
A 
|
X---(a few changes)--- B
|
|(hundreds of changes)
|
HEAD/master
```

If I do "git merge master" from the branch, many merge conflicts are shown, because B and HEAD are very different now. But this seems (naively, to me) wrong: B is not that far from the trunk, it's just a long way back in time.

Is there a way to take advantage of this fact? Should I try and first merge B back to X, then from there to HEAD? What would be the commands to:

1. Identify revision X
2. See differences between B and X
3. Merge B with X
4. Update from that new merged version to HEAD

Is there another approach that people use in these situations?

(Quite possibly I have said some very stupid and un-git-like things in the preceding - feel free to point them out. :))

Comment: Have you tried creating a patch between the two branches and applying it to your current head.

Comment: between X and B you mean? that sounds like what I want to do. can you point me at the right commands?

Comment: Depending on what works best for you a couple of examples may be git diff X..HEAD foo.cc > foo.patch or git diff X..HEAD > all.patch

Comment: answered "1." above by simply reading backwards through "git log".

Comment: @Adrian, looks like this will work. I note one downside is when you apply patches, you lose access to tools like mergetool - and sometimes the patch simply fails.

Comment: maybe using git am --interactive might help you - and I thought you could do the same with git apply - but I cant find it. To me the interactive apply is one of the coolest SCM things Ive seen

Comment: I guess you could try boiling (rebasing) your B branch down to just one commit, then cherry-picking that onto master. Though to be honest, I'm not sure that that will give you anything different than what you're getting already.

Comment: In the end, patches didn't work for this, because they're too fragile, and a patch that won't apply is much, much worse than a normal merge conflict. (There are no tools to help you). Btw you can turn a patch into something that 'am' will work with by pasting in some junk email headers. [Digression: the 'am' command is a hideous monstrosity, the worst kind of linuxy cruft - ew ew ew.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new branch "X" from the point where B and master diverged and then merging B into X won't help you. That would simply be a fast-forward merge; there would be literally *no change* to the conflicts caused by merge B into master. Your only option is to perform the merge of B into master and address the conflicts. Conflicts are what they are, and there is no way "around" them.

Comment: Yeah in the end I think you're right, and this is the approach I took. Good tools would help a lot. Strangely, the conflict resolution tool in Eclipse (well, PyDev anyway) was less good than the generic Mac "opendiff". It's pretty damn hard to manage that many conflicts though, and to make sure nothing gets lost. Good test cases would help, too, I guess.

Comment: @SteveBennett: Tests are indeed great, but only go so far, since if you're merging a really old commit, any tests it added may not be complete anymore, and any tests it changed might be changed in the wrong way.

Comment: Sometimes it may be easier to rebase the old branch on top of the master. This way you have to deal with the merge conflicts per old commit, not work with a huge conflict that results from all the old commits as a result of a single merge.

Comment: Or you could use something like BeyondCompare and go manually?!

Answer (score 1):

If it's bad enough, you might want to just manually rewrite the patch against HEAD or at least a more recent version. This will not only help deal with the conflicts, and leave you a history you'll probably like better, but also help you avoid bugs that *aren't* part of merge conflicts. There's quite a lot of potential for problems due to code changing underneath the change, and not all of it would actually present as a merge conflict.

That said, if you do want to try to do it solely in merge-y ways, you're going to have to deal with these conflicts one way or another. It's *possible* that you could spare yourself some pain by doing it incrementally, stepping forward in time in smaller increments. I might do this by progressively rebasing the branch forward:

```
git rebase version-2 old-branch
# deal with conflicts if they happen
git rebase version-3 old-branch
# and so on...
# until old-branch is based on a recent version
git checkout master
git merge old-branch
```

This would effectively let you deal with smaller changes in each step, instead of dealing with it all at once.